# Reverse sudo - sudo ro untrusted user

Tags: linux, sudo

I want to split my terminal sessions to different users, to compartmentalize them.

If I sudo -i -u user1 in one terminal window,
can user1 attack my main session?

Everyone talks about sudo to escalate privileges, but I want to reduce them.

Comment: In a farther sense: I hate practically all sandbox approaches on linux because they have one or more of these properties: Hard to setup, Hard to maintain, inflexible, full of footguns, incomplete, undocumented, hard to estimate security guarantees.

Comment: Are you familiar with the TIOCSTI attack?

Comment: So the answer is "likely not secure by default"?